# Load all mat files from subdirectories

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, directory, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I have lots of data in .mat format. Moreover, my main data folder has lots of subfolders. Under each subfolders, I have 1000 .mat data files. I want to load all of them by using python. I am trying , but unable to do it automatically. I want help to write a function in which

1. It will go to each directory, and read all the 1000 data files, and
   store them in a single dictionary. All the subfolders are into a folder 
   called Dataset
2. Folder name will give me multulabel information. Such as: one of the
   subfolder name is C1_10_300, so it will make three separate labels
   from the folder name (category, subtype 1, subvar 1) = (c1,10, 300)
   like this.

**NB: Each .mat file has two separate entries: signal, and fs. I only want to consider the signal file.**

I am adding my folder tree picture, and the photo of the variables of each .mat file [image]over here.

Please help me. 
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: You tagged both MATLAB and Python. Which one are you using? Also, what is your question? I don’t see one! All I see is “help me”. Does that mean you want someone to do your work for you? That is not how SO works. Please read [ask].

Comment: First, are you ok with loading the `signal` for one file?  Or for a couple and accumulating the results in some way?  The rest of your task is a matter of getting filenames for the relevant directories and iterating on them.  The usual Python `path` and `glob` modules should be useful.

Comment: In both languages, you can simply write a function that uses `dir` to get all elements of a folder and call this function recursively. Than loop through the returned list to load the files...(and please delete unnecessary tags, such as 'matlab' and 'numpy'!)

Comment: He does say " I want to load all of them by using python", which means using the `scipy.io.loadmat` function. These `.mat` files are MATLAB generated/compatible, which explains that tag.

Comment: I am using both right now. But currently I am willing to do it by python. Sorry for the messed up. @crish luengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this function - it loop over all subfolders and find and load .mat files and load those to a struct, which organizes each folder and file names as subfields.

```
function data=loadmatfromdir(rootdir)
fd=dir(rootdir);
data=struct();
for i=1:length(fd)
    fname=[fd(i).folder filesep fd(i).name];
    if(fd(i).isdir && isempty(regexp(fd(i).name,'^\.{1,2}$', 'once')))
        data.(genvarname(fd(i).name))=loadmatfromdir(fname);
    elseif(regexp(fd(i).name,'\.[Mm][Aa][Tt]'))
        data.(genvarname(fd(i).name))=load(fname);
    end
end
```

if you have a particular variable to load from the .mat file instead of all variables, modify load(..) to add the variable name - for example call `load(fname,'signal')` to load only the signal variable ; if there are specific file name patterns that you want to match, modify the regexp call at the bottom. currently it matches all .mat files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need some more help. The answer is saved as a structure file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The answer is saved as a structure file. I need a matrix where all the files from a particular subfolder will be as 1 single .mat file. Suppose, in C1_10_300 folder,I have some number of signals. I want to have a .mat file which name would be C1_10_300 , and it will have two matrices, one is signal - where I want to have all the signals (each row will represent each signal, and column will contain signal values) and one .mat file called labels, where I will have row=total number of signals, and will have three columns - [C1,10,300] - for all the subfolders. Can u please help me